# how to avoid using "isDebugEnabled()" in Java?

Tags: debugging

When programming in java, debug log is very essential. But it's troublious to input isDebugEnabled everywhere. Is there any way to avoid using this while not affect the performance of the system?

Answer (score 0):

Sort of.

Using slf4j you can do

```
log.debug("{}",someObject);
```

which will only concatenate the someObject.toString() if debug is enabled. Similarly for things like

```
log.debug("Hello {}, i am {} years old",name,age);
```

Check out [this link](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#logging_performance) for more info: